# How to convert completion handler in `init` into async function

Tags: swift, async-await

I have the following initializer in Swift:

```swift
class MyView: UIView {
    init(
        option: MyOption, 
        completionHandler: @escaping (MyResult) -> Void
    ) {
        self.option = option
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        installViews()
    }
}
```

How to convert this into an async equivalent. Generally speaking it's straight forward for regular functions, but `await withCheckedContinuation` might not have been intended for initializers.

Comment: Why do you think that "`await withCheckedContinuation` might not have been intended for initializers"? Can you show an attempt at using it that doesn't work?

Comment: The reason I said "might not have been intended for initializers" is that in this case initialization and completion handlers are used together. How would you return what you've just initialized while at the same time use the continuation to return the completion result? I will update my question with the earlier attempts I made.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you meant now. Can you explain what the completion handler is for? When would it be called normally? Is there a method on the view that, when called, will trigger the completion handler some time later?

Comment: Yes, the completion handler would be called when the user hits a button. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an "OK" button that can only be pressed once before a modal view is dismissed? If not, then it shouldn't be `async`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no async equivalent of this pattern because this is not concurrency. `completionHandler` should really be `action` or `onTap` or something like that. The creator of MyView doesn't await the completion handler (that would be very strange and likely impossible for a UIView), so there's nothing asynchronous about this. The whole point of `async` is that it avoids passing "do this when done" at all. It keeps that code in the caller.

What **would** be async is if this button could be waited on. This is an extremely simple implementation that I haven't studied closely for race conditions, but is the general approach you might use.

```
class MyView: UIView {
    private var tapContinuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Never>?

    // Tracks taps that occur when no one is watching
    private var hasBeenTapped = false

    // Caller awaits the next tap.
    // Note that as written, it is a programming error for multiple things
    // to be waiting. That can be fixed, but is more complex than this example
    public func waitForTap() async {
        if hasBeenTapped {
            hasBeenTapped = false
            return
        }

        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            assert(tapContinuation == nil)
            tapContinuation = continuation
        }
    }

    // At some point, a tap occurs. Either queue it, or release the waiter.
    private func tap() {
        if let tapContinuation {
            tapContinuation.resume()
            self.tapContinuation = nil
        } else {
            hasBeenTapped = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, as always. For the sake of future readers, I’d note that one might reach for some `AsyncSequence`, probably an [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md). An asynchronous sequence would handle the sequence of tap events quite gracefully.

Comment: Great advice. I strongly considered writing this with AsyncChannel, and it's what I use myself when I have this problem. I was too lazy to set up a project with async-algorithms to demonstrate it. :D Definitely worth a look. I tried to build it originally with an AsyncSequence without a AsyncChannel, and it got too annoying. And then I remembered dimsumthinking's book that I've been reading, which advocated this pattern, and I think it works nicely. https://editorscut.gumroad.com/l/async